# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at wheelnav.createWhee

Tags: javascript, wheelnav.js

I have some problems with Wheelnav.js 
When I include the scripts inside my html file, chrome shows this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at wheelnav.createWheel (wheelnav.js:271)
    at window.onload (script.js:14)

this is my script:

```
window.onload = function() {
var wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");

wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
wheel.wheelRadius = 130;
wheel.maxPercent = 1.2;
wheel.colors = colorpalette.oceanfive;
wheel.clickModeRotate = false;
wheel.slicePathFunction = slicePath().WheelSlice;
wheel.navAngle = 30;
wheel.createWheel(["basic", "hover", "select", null, null, null]);

wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
wheel.sliceHoverTransformFunction = 
sliceTransform().RotateTitleTransform;
wheel.sliceSelectedTransformFunction = 
sliceTransform().MoveMiddleTransform;
wheel.wheelRadius = wheel.wheelRadius * 0.8;
wheel.colors = colorpalette.fractallove;

wheel.createWheel(["Thank you", "for", "download", "hello"]);
wheel.navigateWheel(2);

var piemenu = new wheelnav("piemenu");
piemenu.wheelRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 0.83;
piemenu.createWheel();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have a div with the corresponding id.

```
var piemenu = new wheelnav("piemenu");
```

It requires:

```
<div id="piemenu"></div>
```